# JSON parse converts certain number to somethig else

Tags: javascript, json

I have found that some number when passing through `parseInt` are changing to other number.

```
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647662, 10 ) ); //10153315281647662
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647663, 10 ) ); //10153315281647664
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647664, 10 ) ); //10153315281647664
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647665, 10 ) ); //10153315281647664
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647666, 10 ) ); //10153315281647666
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647667, 10 ) ); //10153315281647668
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647668, 10 ) ); //10153315281647668
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647669, 10 ) ); //10153315281647668
console.log( parseInt( 10153315281647660, 10 ) ); //10153315281647660


var str = '{ "id" : 10153315281647663 }';
console.log(  JSON.parse( str ) ) // id : 10153315281647664
```

I was working with few large numbers and `parseInt` or changing `str` to JSON with number is changing the numbers in result. This is not becasuse of integer stack overflow because the larger numbers `10153315281647666` is parsing correctly while `10153315281647663` is not, what can be the reason behind this?

I have fixed the issue by parsing everything into string, but what is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you're trying to parse is too large. It [can't be reliably stored](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) as double-precision floating-point

```js
console.log(10153315281647663 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log(10153315281647663);
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

Comment: But the results do not seem to be "unexpected" or even random. Some are being parsed correctly and some are not and the results are always exactly the same for a given number. Is there a reason behind that?

Comment: @developernaren: That's because the least significant bit is lost. I'll (try to) add in an explanation.

Comment: I can't really come up with a proper explanation without it resulting in a wall of text. Here's a better resource that explains why you're seeing the numbers you're seeing:  http://blog.vjeux.com/2010/javascript/javascript-max_int-number-limits.html

Answer (score 0):

No need to parse the numbers it is just the end of the maximal possible count of places without loosing precision of the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) format.

```js
console.log(10153315281647662); //10153315281647662
console.log(10153315281647663); //10153315281647664
console.log(10153315281647664); //10153315281647664
console.log(10153315281647665); //10153315281647664
console.log(10153315281647666); //10153315281647666
console.log(10153315281647667); //10153315281647668
console.log(10153315281647668); //10153315281647668
console.log(10153315281647669); //10153315281647668
console.log(10153315281647660); //10153315281647660
```